# retrieve only second row of the table in oracle?

Tags: oracle

Can anyone help, how to retrieve exactly 2nd row from the table in oracle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the rows in a table are inherently unordered, the concept of "first" and "second" requires that you specify some way of enforcing order (i.e. an ORDER BY clause).  The simplest way to do this is to use an analytic function

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY some_column) rn
          FROM your_table a)
 WHERE rn = 2;
```

You could also use ROWNUM though that requires an additional level of nesting

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT b.*, rownum rn
          FROM (SELECT *
                  FROM your_table a
                 ORDER BY some_column) b
         WHERE rownum <= 2)
 WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: I guess not having a top keyword is another reason to join the "I hate Oracle club" :) http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/t/1142.aspx

Comment: Or a `LIMIT` keyword, for that matter.  I mean, come on...even MySQL can do stuff like this without resorting to subqueries inside subqueries.  And the fun part...doesn't Oracle own MySQL now?

Answer (score -5):

Thanks for your answers,now i found the solution for this,

```
      select * from
        (select rownum rn,column1,column2,...,columnn from tablename)
      where
         rn=2
```

Now you can check this and post your valuable comments.

Comment: Since your subquery does not specify a row order, this statement *might* return different rows on every execution.

Comment: Further, because rownum = 1 is being filtered out, rownum = 2 will never be found.

Comment: @Adam: no, the filter is on rn which is not filtered until the outer query runs, so this will work; albeit randomly as Martin says.

Comment: @Martin: Its return second row on every execution. Please check out.

Comment: your query will always return the second row of the *resultset*, but that is not necessarily always the *same row* of table "tablename".

Comment: -1 - accepted 'own' answer to question fails to correctly answer the question.